# Allowing mouse events to bubble reliably through the youtube chromeless player?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, youtube, youtube-api

**Hello all!**

I'm working on a prototype that would require me being able to read and track the mouse movement over a playing youtube video. The basic code to replicate my problem boils down to this simple test case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
layout="absolute"
initialize="{go();}">
<mx:VBox>
  <mx:Label id="test" text=""/>
  <mx:SWFLoader source="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3" />
</mx:VBox>
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    function go(){
    Security.allowDomain("*");
    Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,
                     function(e:MouseEvent){trace(test.text=e.stageX+"")});
    }
  ]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Expected behavior is:

- Youtube player loads
- The label on the top right tracks the X coordinate of the mouse
- The number should update even when moving the mouse over the Youtube player

So far the program **behaves as expected when running from the IDE** (tested on both FlashDevelop and FlashBuilder) and even when running the file manually from the output folder. But, alas, when I try to run it from *anywhere* else than the debug folder (be it another location on my computer or up on a webserver), the Youtube player seems to eat the events.

I don't get sandbox security warnings when debugging (thanks to allowDomain("*")) but I'm running out of ideas on why the program fails *once you take the file out of the debug folder*.

I would **immensely** appreciate any clues. Please note that as far as solutions go, I'm willing to try a different tech than flash if you have a proof of that working somewhere else.

Comment: Can I ask what's the point?  What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?  Also, you should set the applicationDomain on the swf loader to be the same as your application like this: `applicationDomain="{ApplicationDomain.currentDomain}"`

Comment: I'm trying to integrate youtube videos in a game prototype where the user would be requested to click on or drag over objects in a given video.

Aside from that, I think it would be nice to have properly behaving mouse events to allow more normal operations, like drag-drop?

Comment: Gotcha.  Again, make sure the applicationDomain is the same.  It should work then.

Comment: I've tried configuring the application domain, but alas, no change in behavior. Searching the YouTube API boards seems to indicate that I'm not the only one having encountered this strange behavior. I'll try asking there if no alternative comes up here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I'm answering my own answer (I know...) only to let it recorded somewhere if someone needs it.

As much as I tried, there was no success with tweaking the security sandbox settings. I even tried all possible combinations, and no dice.

What I did do, out of desperation, was actually adding mouse listeners to the `Loader.content` property once loading is finished. And it worked well enough.

It's the only place I've found where a loading application can safely access the loadee's mouse events without obstructing its inner mouse logic.

Hope it helps someone else get unstuck in the future!